# Datedif and If statement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to create an Excel formula that allows me to calculate the datedif of the month (i.e. Date of Expiry - Today's Date). Which I have done as seen below:

[image]

This is my formula:

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF($F$1,C4,"m") & " Months", "Already Expired")
```

However, I want a formula that can take note of the (s) in Months if the months left is only 1 Month. 
(I.e. I do not want the s behind the Months if the "m" in datedif is just 1 month difference.) 
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Another IF. Check if `DATEDIF($F$1,C4,"m")` =1, then return `Month` else `Months`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the unit into the cell format, not the formula. The formula should produce an integer and the cell format should be *Custom* `[=1]0 "month";0 "months"`.

To test, format a cell as described above and enter any number. The cell will display the number and the word "moth" or "months", depending upon the value you entered.